# jQuery Ajax not working in IE 9 or older

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I use jQuery with ajax and it is working in all browsers except for IE 9 or older. **jQuery itself works,** but not the ajax calls. I use the following code:

HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
if ($('#page-home').length) {
    var $targetDivOffers = $('#results-recent-offers');

    var query = {};
    query = {
        status: 'all',
        category: 'all',
        limit: 3
    };

    // first load recent gesuche
    query.type = 1;

    $targetDivOffers.html('');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "system/process-get-adverts.php",
        data: query,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false
    }).done(function (html) {
        $('.ajax-loader').show().delay(300).promise().done(function () {
            $('.ajax-loader').fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
                $targetDivOffers.html(html.results);
            });
        });
    }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        $targetDivOffers.html("Request Failed: " + err);
        });
}
```

What could be there about my code that makes it not working in IE9 or older?

**UPDATE**

I tried to minimalize my code in order to check if I integrated jQuery properly. The following code still does not work in IE 9 or less:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]--> <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta title="Test">
</head>

<body>

<p id="test"></p>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.joind.in/v2.1/talks/10889',
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            var $title = $('<h1>').text(data.talks[0].talk_title);
            var $description = $('<p>').text(data.talks[0].talk_description);
            $('#test')
                .append($title)
                .append($description);
        },
        type: 'GET'
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

What is wrong about this code?

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: "not working" isn't a useful problem description. What errors do you see in the F12 Dev Tools? Do the calls just not complete at all? Complete and call `fail`? Set your computer on fire?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I think it's the last one. It's definitely on fire !

Comment: I use jQuery 1.11.2. I don't have IE9 installed on my computer, but I have checked via IE NetRenderer and my ajax loader does not show up, whereas in IE versions above 9 it does.

Comment: I have updated my code. I created a test file. The code above at the end of my post STILL does not work in IE 9 or less.

Comment: can you try putting your ajax call inside 
$( document ).ready(function() {
/*code here*/
});

Comment: @Doro: Your example works for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/fcmp3d5e/1

Answer (score 0):

It may be Jquery not loading properly.
try as below:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>  
    <script src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>  
<![endif]-->  
<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (!IE)]><!-->  
    <script src="jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>  
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Another reason can be jQuery/IE does not correctly urlencode double quotes and shows in URL ("") instead of encoded double quotes (%22).

Comment: I tried, but this didnt't work either. 
 
I have updated my code. I created a test file. The code above at the end of my post STILL does not work in IE 9 or less.